# Pandas Conditional Columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I need to take specific text from Column A and based on it, I need to create a new column and add values to it.

| Device_users |
| --- |
| Old_Android_user |
| New_Android_user |
| Old_IOS_user |

Say I have the above column, I want to use it to create a new column:

| Device_users | Fan |
| --- | --- |
| Old_Android_user | Google_fan |
| New_Android_user | Google_fan |
| Old_IOS_user | Apple_fan |

So if there's 'Android' in column A then the new column should return 'Google_fan' or 'IOS', then 'Apple_fan'. Plus the new column created should have the title 'Fan'

Answer (score 1):

Try with `str.contains`

```
df['Fan'] = np.where(df.Device_users.str.contains('Android'),'Google_fan','Apple_fan')
df
Out[13]: 
       Device_users         Fan
0  Old_Android_user  Google_fan
1  New_Android_user  Google_fan
2      Old_IOS_user   Apple_fan
```